# Trying to avoid .toarray() when loading data into an SVC model in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to plug a bunch of data (sentiment-tagged tweets) into an SVM using scikit-learn. I've been using CountVectorizer to build a sparse array of word counts, and it's all working fine with smallish data sets (~5000 tweets). However, when I try to use a larger corpus (ideally 150,000 tweets, but I'm currently exploring with 15,000), `.toarray()`, which converts a sparse format to a denser format, immediately starts taking up immense amounts of memory (30k tweets hit over 50gb before the MemoryError.

So my question is -- is there a way to feed `LinearSVC()` or a different manifestation of SVM a sparse matrix? Am I necessarily required to use a dense matrix? It doesn't seem like a different vectorizer would help fix this problem (as this problem seems to be solved by: [MemoryError in toarray when using DictVectorizer of Scikit Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251959/memoryerror-in-toarray-when-using-dictvectorizer-of-scikit-learn)). Is a different model the solution? It seems like all of the scikit-learn models require a dense array representation at some point, unless I've been looking in the wrong places.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer=str.split)
clf = svm.LinearSVC()

X = cv.fit_transform(data)
trainArray = X[:breakpt].toarray()
testArray = X[breakpt:].toarray()

clf.fit(trainArray, label)
guesses = clf.predict(testArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LinearSVC.fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.fit) and its `predict` method can both handle a sparse matrix as the first argument, so just removing the `toarray` calls from your code should work.

All estimators that take sparse inputs are documented as doing so. E.g., the docstring for `LinearSVC` states:

```
Parameters
----------
X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
    Training vector, where n_samples in the number of samples and
    n_features is the number of features.
```

Comment: wow - I can't believe I missed that, thanks for pointing it out